# Why not determine how long to wait between meat and milk using science?

Tags: food, meat, meat-and-milk, science, dairy

If the time required to wait between eating meat and milk is based on the scientific definition of digestion, why don't we ask today's experts and set a defined time for everyone instead of different people following different customs?

Comment: This questioned IMHO would be better expressed as "why don't we change our customs to fit science?"

Comment: Because it's not based on the scientific definition of digestion, if one exists anyway. How would you decide when the food is "totally" digested? When x% of the molecules have been converted to waste? When x% of the waste molecules has been expelled from the body?

Comment: @SethJ I'm guessing a Gastro probably has an accurate definition of this. If it's not based on digestion what is it based on?

Comment: @PM good question. It's a bit of a controversy.  http://machonshilo.org/en/eng/list-audio-shiurim/41-audiohalakha/395-meat-and-milk-series

Comment: @avi can you summarize?

Comment: @PM I can't, I havn't heard it myself, only heard people talking about it.  And I have my own opinions not based on that and don't want to conflate them.  But basically you have many statemetns in the talmud, anywhere from no wait at all to 24 hours between meat and milk. Then you also have a from when you change tabletops, to when you eat your next meal, to when the meat is gone from your teeth. it's a complicated topic that hopefully can be fully writen up as an answer.

Comment: Re "why don't we ask today's experts and set a defined time for everyone": Suppose we could get a good modern-science definition of digestion. Why do you think everyone would do that in the same amount of time? I doubt it.

Comment: The difference in time between one person and the next is likely less than an hour.

Comment: @msh210 i don't think it would be based on time but rather on consumption. something like 1lb of food = 1hr to digest or something. Then tweaks based on food type (like hard cheese) would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

Waiting six hours is not based on the scientific definition of digestion. The Talmud ([Chullin 105a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=105&format=pdf)) says that one must wait from one meal to the next. There is a disagreement among the Rishonim if that actually means from one meal to the next, or if it means the amount of time between the morning and evening meals, which would mean approximately six hours. See YD 89. The reason for the wait according to these Rishonim is either that fat/grease from the meat that is in one's throat emits a meat flavor into one's mouth for a long time (Rashi) or that for that amount of time we are concerned that small pieces of meat might be stuck between one's teeth (Rambam). Neither of these reasons say that these issues last exactly six hours, but rather that the Sages drew a line at six hours, and neither of them have to do with digestion per se.

Answer (score 5):

For Ashkenazim at least, the **halacha** is like Tosafot, that once one finishes the meat meal, if he starts a new meal he may consume dairy. However, in the common case, people follow their **minhag** of how long to wait. See the Rama in Shulchan Aruch [Yoreh Deah 89:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%98), as I've seen it traditionally understood -- that he paskens like the יש אומרים that one needs not wait, but that it is a מנהג הפשוט במדינות אלו to wait, rather than a decided halacha -- such that in cases of great need, this minhag may be relaxed.

If so, the science won't help.