# Waiting 3 hours to eat dairy after eating meat

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Is it true that there is no true halachic time one must wait to eat dairy after eating meat for Ashkenazim? (Of course, eating it in the same meal is a sin, and is not allowed!) So by waiting 3 hours after eating meat to eat dairy, do I fulfill the Mitzvah of waiting between meat and dairy? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. VTC as unclear

Comment: It's not really a mitzvah possibly. As David Kenner explains below Sefardim generally hold 6 hours is halachikly the minimum. Ashkenazim generally have minhagim of 6, 3 hours, or 1 hour etc. Therefore you have to whatever your minhag is. You can't just switch. If youre a convert/ger and do not yet have minhagim then you could choose any of the minhagim. If you already have a minhag of say 6 hours then you would have to do Hatarat Nedarim/annulment if vows with a Beis Din/court if you would like to do a shorter amount.  CYLOR if you plan to do anything practically and not just theoretically.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If there is no "true halachic time" one must wait then what is "the Mitzvah of waiting"?

Comment: Is your question "is it true one can dairy immediately after meat but not at the same meal" and therefore waiting 3 hours is really going beyond the law? (by the way there is no mitzva to wait, there is a (negative) mitzva not to eat meat and dairy together)

Comment: I don't know what you are asking but probably some of these cover it.

Answer (score 3):

The source you are looking for is the Rema's (Rabbi Moshe Isserles) commentary for Ashkenazim on the Shulchan Aruch. [Yoreh Deah 89:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.89.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

It starts with the opinion of R' Yosef Karo (Tzefardim usually follow him.):

> **One who eats meat**, even of a wild animal or fowl, **does not eat
>   cheese afterwards** **until he waits six hours**. Even if he waits
>   that period, if he has meat between his teeth he has to remove it. One
>   who chews food for a child has to wait.

The Rema then comments by saying that some hold you do not need to wait any amount of time at all from meat to milk. Then he says the Ashkenazi custom he is familiar with in his locale is 1 hour. Finally at the end, he does endorse the 6 hour time frame used by R' Yosef Karo.

> "...There are those that says that **he doesn't have to wait** six
>   hours, **but rather immediately** if he finishes the (meat) meal and
>   says the concluding blessing, **it is permissible** after wiping and
>   rinsing his mouth (Tosafot Hullin 105a - "At the next meal", Mordechai
>   chapter 25, Haga'ot Ashri, Haga'ot Maimoniot chapter 9 of forbidden
>   foods, and Ravya). **The simple custom in our countries is to wait
>   after eating meat one hour and to eat cheese afterwards**, but you
>   have to say the concluding blessing after the meat (HaAruch, Haga'ot
>   Shaarei Dura) because then it's like a new meal and permissible to eat
>   according to the lenient view. But with no blessing, waiting alone
>   does no good. It doesn't matter if you waited before the blessing or
>   afterwards (his own reasoning, from the Mahari, as opposed to the
>   Issur v'Heter). If he finds meat between his teeth after the hour, he
>   has to pull it out (his own reasoning, from the Ran above). And there
>   are those that say not to say the concluding blessing in order to eat
>   cheese (Aruch in the name of Maharach) but we're not careful about
>   this. **And some are careful to wait six hours after eating meat
>   before eating cheese, and it's proper to do so.**"

So the Shulchan Aruch does not mention a concept of 3 hours. It is either nothing, 1 hour, or six hours.

However, other authorities say or suggest other amounts of time in between 0 - 6 hours. If you just wanted to know if there is an opinion that you only need 0 or 1 hour for Ashkenazim, then yes, there is such an opinion. Your concept of 3 hours certainly fulfills the more lenient opinions which require less waiting time.

Origin (sources) of the three hour wait can be found discussed here:

[Sources for 3 hour time limit (not Rb. Yerucham)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77114/sources-for-3-hour-time-limit-not-rb-yerucham/77157#77157)

As always, this answer is for learning purposes. If someone has a true question about how many hours they should or should not be waiting between meat and milk, they should consult their personal Orthodox Rabbi for guidance on what is right for them.