Waiting between meat and milk
I once heard that the historical reason of why we wait between meat and milk comes from the rivalry between the Sadducees and Pharisees; In order to separate one group from the other, one of the groups instated a waiting period between meat and dairy meals (as opposed to having them serves at different courses).
Could anyone expand on this / confirm it / debunk it?

Do you have a source to this?

It wasn't the Sadducees but the Karaites https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61961/759

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
